# Finding a count column based on 3 different column in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data frame in the form of:

```
user_id referral_code referred_by
1        A              None
2        B              A
3        C              B
5        None           None
6        E              B
7        None           none

....
```

What I want to do is to create another column weight for each user id such that it will contain the total number of references he has done to others as well as the the number of time he was referred i.e I have to check if the referral_code of a user id is present in the referred_by column and count the frequency of the same and also add 1 if the referred_by column has a entry for the user.

Expected output is:

```
user_id referral_code referred_by weights
1        A              None       1
2        B              A          3
3        C              B          1
5        None           None       None
6        E              B          1
7        None           none       none
```

The approaches if have tried is using `df.grouby` along with `size` and `count` but nothing is giving the expected output.

Comment: Why `weights = 3` for `B` ? (row 2)

Comment: @AlexandreB. Because for user id 2 he was referred by A. And he then he himself refers others (in this case 3 and 6). So 1+2.

Comment: So why is there 1 for row 1 ?

Comment: Because 1 was not referred by anyone but he has referred another one( B in this case). So 0+1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to build a **new conditional column**. If the conditions are simple enough, you can do it with `np.where`. I suggest you to have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column).

Here, it's quite complex, there shoud have a solution with `np.where` but not really obvious. In this case, you can use the `apply` method. It gives you the opportunity the write conditions as complex as you want. Using `apply` is less efficient than `np.where` since you need a `python` abstraction. Depends on your dataset and the complexity of your conditions.

Here an example with `apply`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, "A" ,   None],
    [2 , "B" ,   "A"],
    [3 , "C" ,   "B"],
    [5 , None,   None],
    [6 , "E"  ,  "B"],
    [7 , None ,  None]],
    columns = 'user_id referral_code referred_by'.split(' ')
)
print(df)
#    user_id referral_code referred_by
# 0        1             A        None
# 1        2             B           A
# 2        3             C           B
# 3        5          None        None
# 4        6             E           B
# 5        7          None        None

weight_refered_by = df.referred_by.value_counts()
print(weight_refered_by)
# B    2
# A    1

def countWeight(row):
    count = 0

    if row['referral_code'] in weight_refered_by.index:
        count = weight_refered_by[row.referral_code]

    if row["referred_by"] != None:
        count += 1

    # If referral_code is none, result is none 
    # because referred_by is included in referral_code
    if row["referral_code"] == None:
        count = None
    return count

df["weights"] = df.apply(countWeight, axis=1)
print(df)
#    user_id referral_code referred_by  weights
# 0        1             A        None      1.0
# 1        2             B           A      3.0
# 2        3             C           B      1.0
# 3        5          None        None      NaN
# 4        6             E           B      1.0
# 5        7          None        None      NaN
```

Hope that help !

Comment: thanks. Does the work. Although I tried by converting the dataframe to list and perform the  operation, this solution works better.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is using `weights = df.referred_by.value_counts()['myword']+1` and then add it to your df in the column weights !

Comment: What is `['my word']` here?

Comment: Your letter like `df.referred_by.value_counts()['A']` or `df.referred_by.value_counts()['B']`